# Animate buttons and move them down when a new UITextView is made visible

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton, uitextfield

My code is all in Swift. I have 5 `UITextFields`. 3 of them are hidden when the `view` loads. Under the first 2 `UITextFields` there's a "+" `UIButton` that should make the  additional `UITextField` visible (up to 3 more `UITextFields`, 5 in total). All the 5 `UITextFields` are already added in the `UIStoryboard`, they're simply set to be `hidden`.

When the user taps that "+" `UIButton`, the "set expiration date" `UIButton` and the "+" `UIButton` show be animated and set under the third `UITextField`. Every time the user taps on the "+" `UIButton`, the same `+` and "set expiration date" buttons should slide down under the newly added (made visible) `UITextField`.

Not visible on the screenshot below, but there will a "delete" `UIButton` for the 3rd, 4th and 5th `UITextFields`. Once they delete one of them, the "+" and "set expiration date" `UIButtons` should go up and stay under the last `UITextField` that's visible on the view. Not sure how to accomplish that. Should I set constraints somehow and animate those? How would I know how many `UITextFields` are visible on the view?

Here's what the `UIViewController` looks like right now.

[image]

Comment: Put the text fields and button in a `UIStackView`

Comment: And then what? That's the easy part haha :)

Comment: Then just set the `isHidden` property on your text views inside an animation block and the stack view will do everything else for you

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it will be that simple haha. Thank you! Can you just add that as an answer so I can close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rather simple, Put the text fields and button in a `UIStackView` and then just set the `isHidden` property on your text views inside an animation block and the stack view will do everything else for you. Credit to [@Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029096/animate-buttons-and-move-them-down-when-a-new-uitextview-is-made-visible#comment89051678_51029096)